# outlook pst need to share with diffrent user microsoft outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

I am on resign and my manager has asked me to share my outlook pst with him on share drive? My only concern can he missue that outlook pst. I mean that from that pst can he login into my outlook accont or like can he send emails from my outlook account? Please help.

Comment: Is this a PST of a personal email address or a work email address belonging to the company? If it belongs to the company they can get the data themselves, and have the right to the information. If it's your own personal email account and you were using it for work, you could put the work relevant emails into their own PST and send it to your boss. He wouldn't get any account access info from that.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to remove the password from the PST file. That way your manager does not need the password.

[Remove PST password](https://www.slipstick.com/problems/pst-repair/remove-a-password-from-a-pst-file/)

> If you know the password but are tired of using it, you can remove it
> or change it and save it to your password list. If you can't remember
> the password, see Tools for utilities that can show you the password.
>
> 1. Right click on the .pst file name in your folder list.
> 2. Choose Properties (Data Files Properties in Outlook 2010 and newer), then Advanced button.
> 3. Click Change Password button.

Also, you may wish to first load up the PST on your system and remove any emails not related to your company.

Comment: hi john thank you for the answer one more thing like i am sharing him my pst so can he use that pst to send email from my account. i have this doubt i do not want that to happen

Comment: If you remove or change the password, then I do not think the manager can send email on your account.

Comment: Also, sharing the PST gives him the email information. I understand that part of it. But if no password, he cannot send email on your account; he has to use his own account.

Comment: Thank you i will remove the password and then share the pst. thank you

Comment: Access to your PST **DOES NOT** give anyone access to an ability to send mail as someone else. They can view your work emails, the PST in question, is limited to work emails, right? If your manager has the right to access your work emails entirely depends on your jurisdiction. We cannot determine if you should or shouldn’t share the PST file.

Answer (score 0):

What does your manager need to see in your email? Maybe you can try to export the content he needs to a .pst file and send it to him.

For more information about exporting to a .pst file, please refer to:

[Export or backup email, contacts, and calendar to an Outlook .pst file.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91)

Comment: I am writing to see how everything is going on with this thread. Should you need more help on this, you can feel free to post back.